# How to initialise subclasses when the parent class uses a classmethod?

Tags: python, oop

So let's say I have this code structure:

```py
class Parent:

    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.a = a,
        self.b = b
        self.c = c

    @classmethod
    def from_string(cls, some_string):
        if some_string == 'duh':
            return cls(a=5, b=6, c='banana')
        else:
            return cls(a=0, b=0, c='chicken')

    def method_1(self):
        #do something

    def method_2(self):
        #do something else

class FirstChild(Parent):
  
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        super().__init__(a, b, c)

    def child_specific_method(self):
        #do something

class SecondChild(Parent):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        super().__init__(a, b)

    def some_other_method(self):
        #do stuff
```

My thinking was that I want both subclasses to have access to methods of the Parent class, but also extend its functionality. At the same time I want the Parent class to instantiate with different parameters based on the class method.

Now I'm confused as to how I would create instances of child classes? Or, more precisely, how would I create child instances when there can be different versions of the parent class?

Comment: See the factory pattern. https://stackabuse.com/the-factory-method-design-pattern-in-python/

Comment: The problem or question is not clear. All of these work with your current code (after adding missing `pass` statements): `FirstChild(1, 2, 3)`, `FirstChild.from_string('duh')`, and `FirstChild.from_string('blort')`. What, specifically, would you like to do that you can't currently do?

Comment: Oh yeah, so that was exactly what I was wondering about. So the way to instantiate a child class based on one of the versions of the parent class is to do `FirstChild.from_string('duh')`. That solves it!